# Merging three dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to merge three data frames a,b,c together on the column-'tweet_id' which is present in all three data frames. I have converted the data type to string in all three data frames. Despite taking all the precautions, after merging, the resultant data frame does not have a single row.[converting the data type to string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRMVN.jpg) [Merging the dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOyPk.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post pics. Instead paste a sample of all dataframes as code with the final expected output.

Comment: [do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: have you tried `how='outer'` instead of `'inner'`? Seems like your twitter ids don't match

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a.tweet_id = a.tweet_id.astype("string")
```

Instead of

```
a.tweet_id = a.tweet_id.astype(str)
```

The former converts the column type to string, whereas the latter converts it to `object`, which is corroborated by the screenshot you took. This might be causing your merge problem.

Comment: Nope still the same result.

Comment: It might also be a data problem. Did you verify that there are matching `tweet_id`s in the three dataframes?